# How do i use wildcards in PDO Prepare?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wildcard

I am working on a script using PDO to access my mysql server. My idea is to post/get the category and subcategory that i am interested in to the script. If the script does not receive any input i want it to use a wild card and get all the categories/subcategories. However, when both variables are set to '%' i only receive the rows which has 0 and not entries which has 1, 2, 3.... etc. as kat_id and subkat_id. Can somebody identify what i am doing wrong and how i can change my code to output all my entries when i am not %kat_id and $subkat_id is set to '%'

Below is my code, i am greatful for all the help i can get.

```
<?PHP 
//header("content-type: application/json"); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("../dbconfig.inc.php"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

// Ta emot variiabler
if( isset($_GET['kat_id'])) {
$kat_id =  $_GET['kat_id'];
} else { $kat_id =  '%';};

if( isset($_GET['subkat_id'])) {
$subkat_id =  $_GET['subkat_id'];
} else { $subkat_id =  '%';};


$i = 1;


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM transaktioner WHERE kat_id = :kategori_id AND subkat_id = :subkategori_id");

// Execute
$stmt->execute( array(

            'kategori_id' => $kat_id,
            'subkategori_id' => $subkat_id,
            )

            );

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{

 $r[$i]= $row;

  $i++;  
}

    var_dump ($r);
    //echo '('. json_encode($r) . ')';
```

Comment: Easiest way is to simply omit the clause.

Comment: ^ yeah - what is actually being attempted with that code is something more like `WHERE kat_id = '%'` which, I'm guessing, is not the intended behaviour.

Comment: The `%` expression works with `like` clauses, so yes.

Comment: I made it work with 'like'. Of course it is a stupid statement if both are set as wild card but most of the times the kat_id will be assigned a number but at the same time i want to be able to show all the subcat. I also want to have the possibility to do the opposit and only look a a certain subkat.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of using wildcards is wrong. Both in implementation and intention. Wildcards in SQL aren't used this way.

When no category chosen, no filter have to be added in the query at all. So, with no filters set, just

```
SELECT * FROM transaktioner
```

it have to be, without WHERE clause.

Just a note

```
foreach($result as $row)
{

 $r[$i]= $row;

  $i++;  
}
```

is a quite funny bit of code. `$result` **already** contains your data, and there is no use for duplicating it in a loop.

Comment: I agree that is the case when I do not want to filter anything but lets say that i want category to be 3 and i want to see all the subkategories with in the 3rd category? Do you suggest that i solve this  by giving the whole "prepare statement" within different if statements?